# Activate Smart Pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I wanted to play around with the new features of C++11, namely with `Smart Pointers`. I found an exampleg++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 here: [Cplusplus11-Smart-Pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus11-Smart-Pointers):

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> sptr1( new int );
}
```

When I try it out is everything I get:

```
In function ‘int main()’:|
error: ‘shared_ptr’ was not declared in this scope|
error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’|
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’|
```

This is my g++ Version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
```

Do I have to "activate" C++11 at first?

Comment: You need to use the `-std=c++11` compiler flag.

Comment: Where can I enter that flag? I use Code::Blocks 10.05.

Comment: Settings > Compiler > Compiler Settings > Other Options

Comment: I think there is also a check box for that in compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add this as an answer so that I can close that thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `-std=c++11` compiler flag to the g++ compiler. CodeBlocks allows you to configure this via

> Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler Settings

**Note** for older versions of gcc, you may need `-std=c++0x`.